# Invalid identifier: Amount__c in trigger in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-communities

I have a trigger on a master-detail object where `Doctor` is master and `Patient` is child. `Doctor` has a field called `TotalAmount` and `Patient` has a field called `Amount`. Now, when a patient is filling in the amount field, the `TotalAmount` field in `Doctor` should give the sum of `Amount` in all the patient records.

I have written the code below, but it shows an error:

> Invalid identifier: Amount__c

How can I fix this?

```
trigger tgPatient on Patient__c (after insert,after update) {
    Set<Id>SetDoctor = new Set<Id>(); 
    for (Patient__c p : trigger.new) {
        if( p.Amount__c != Null ) {
            SetDoctor.add(p.Doctor__c);
        }
    }
    List<Doctor> lstDoctor = new List<Doctor>();
    for( Doctor__c d : [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id,Amount__c FROM Patients__r) FROM Doctor__c WHERE Id IN:SetDoctor]){
        Integer Amount__c = 0; 
        for (Patient__c p : d.Patient__r) {
            int Amount__c += p.Amount__c;
        }
        d.Total_Amount__c = int Amount__c;
        lstDoctor.add(d);
    }
    update lstDoctor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one:

```
trigger tgPatient on Patient__c (after insert,after update) {
  Set<Id>SetDoctor = new Set<Id>(); 
   for (Patient__c p : trigger.new){
    if( p.Amount__c != Null  ){
        SetDoctor.add(p.Doctor__c);
    }
 }
 List<Doctor> lstDoctor = new List<Doctor>();

    for( Doctor__c d : [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id,Amount__c FROM Patients__r) FROM Doctor__c WHERE Id IN:SetDoctor]){
      Integer amountVAR = 0; 
        for (Patient__c p : d.Patient__r){
             amountVAR += p.Amount__c;
        }
        d.Total_Amount__c = amountVAR ;
        lstDoctor.add(d);
    }
    update lstDoctor;
```

regards 
ajay

Comment: Hi Ajay,
It shows '' Illegal assignment from Decimal to Integer "
at the line--> amountVAR += p.Amount__c;

Comment: use integer.ValueOf

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
trigger tgPatient on Patient__c(after insert, after update) {
    Set < Id > SetDoctor = new Set < Id > ();
    for (Patient__c p: trigger.new) {
        if (p.Amount__c != Null) {
            SetDoctor.add(p.Doctor__c);
        }
    }
    List < Doctor > lstDoctor = new List < Doctor > ();

    for (Doctor__c d: [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, Amount__c FROM Patients__r) FROM Doctor__c WHERE Id IN: SetDoctor]) {
        d.Total_Amount__c = 0;
        for (Patient__c p: d.Patient__r) {
            d.Total_Amount__c += p.Amount__c;
        }
        lstDoctor.add(d);
    }
    update lstDoctor;
}
```

But why do you want to use a Trigger? Why not create a roll-up summary field on Doctor?

[Creating Roll Up Summary fields](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_defining_summary_fields.htm&language=en_US&type=0)

Comment: Hi Arun,
Yes we can do this by Roll-up but because of some constraint we are required to use trigger!